# How to make git-svn act like the keyword expansion of SVN?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, keyword-expansion

Git has limited keyword expansion capabilities. I know that I should write some scripts that actually do the expansion, because git itself won't. Right now I'm not that worried about the expansion actually being done.

My problem is that I have to work with an SVN repository and I would like to use it with git-svn. However, this specific SVN repository (that I have no control over) has some pre-commit hooks set which requires the files having keyword expansions.

How can I at least trick SVN to believe that I have those keyword expansions set?